# Problem with CSS INLINE code (Login page)

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I am a student new to CSS and Oracle database. I have been working on making an application and creating a self-made login-page.

The code that I have used for this is:

Should I save the image in a document and then change the address. Because the current address points to google images which I don't think it will accept that format.

```
 span.t-login-logo {
    background-image: URL ('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-database-technology-blue- 
    connections-background_92753-212.jpg');
    background-size: cover
    width: 120px; 
    height:120;    
}  

    background-image: URL ('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-database-technology-blue- 
    connections-background_92753-212.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    bckground-size: cover; 
}

    .t-login-region {
    position: relative;
    width: 410 px; 
    Margin: 0 auto;
    background: rbga (130,130,130,.3);
    padding: 20px 22px;
    border-top-color: rbgs (255,255,255,.4);
    border-left-color: rbgs (255,255,255,.4); 
    border-bottom-color: rbgs (60,60,60,.60);
    border-right-color: rbgs (60,60,60,.60);
}
```

Comment: sorry this quote should be at the bottom 'Should I save the image in a document and then change the address. Because the current address points to google images which I don't think it will accept that format.'

Comment: Hi. You missed a `;` in `span.t-login-logo ` - Line 3 - `background-size: cover`